# Android App for mobile website

Tags: android, html

I'm looking to build an android app based off a mobile site. Basically, I just need an app with a browser that I can use as a platform.

Many of the "build an app online" sites offer this, where you just put in the home url etc, but they all include their own ads etc.

Any ideas where to start?

Comment: Use a WebView in a single Activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make your own simple app without Ads, use just a WebView inside of a simgle activity layout set to fill the screen.

Doing this you will eliminate all ads, as well as have the ability to add in more features later on if you so choose.

If you just want to create a launcher icon that will open up the default browser to your sites page, you can do that by just starting a browser intent, and then closing the actual app.

This will allow you to have an app icon and play store listing, however the only thing that iw will do is bring the user to your website like you have mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Create an Activity with a [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for an app that displays a WebView. However, that will only display the website as if you were looking at it in a mobile browser such as Android Chrome.

If you want the *data* from a mobile site, without anything else, then you have to hope that the site provides that, or you have to download its HTML and scrape it.